# What is the meaning of "at least as close as"?

Tags: meaning, difference, logic

Suppose there are two locations: **A** and **B**. It is given that **A** is closer to *me* than **B**, or **A** and **B** are equidistant.

Which of the following statements are logically correct?

1. **A** is at least as close as **B**
2. **B** is at least as close as **A**
3. **A** is at most as close as **B**

I feel that the first statement is correct. However, if seen logically "at least" means "greater than or equal to", so by that logic **A** would be at a greater distance than **B**.

The statement: "**B** is at least as far as **A**" is logically correct. But I am getting confused with the other statements.

Can somebody please explain the logical meaning of these statements?

Comment: If you are asking about "logic" then be aware that English is no more logical than any other natural language.

Comment: @JamesK I understand that. However, I would like to know what do these statements mean in English. Even if it is not logically sound.

Comment: In the first sentence of the question, I believe you had meant to write *it is given that A is **as** close to me **as** B*. Otherwise, I would have assumed a typo of *it is given that A is **closer** to me than B*, but, from the rest of the question, I don't think that's what you meant.

Comment: With that understanding, and ***if*** A and B are *actually* equally close, than *all three* sentences are true—and logically correct. (But if either A or B is farther away, then at least one of the sentences will be incorrect.)

Comment: @JasonBassford I have edit the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "A is as least as close as B" means A is closer than B, or A and B are equidistant.

You might use a phrase like this rhetorically:

> I want to visit Scotland this summer.
>   What about France?
>   I'd rather go to Scotland. Its close!
>   What do you mean? France is as least as close as Scotland, and the weather is better!

So the second sentence is the opposite (B is closer) and the third sentence is not used. Literally the third sentence is "A is equal or further than B" but we wouldn't express it like that, even if we were making a point.

Answer (score 1):

I am a great believer in the notion that natural languages do not **always** meet the **logical** rigor of mathematics or logic, (and a good thing too) but there is no disagreement here between logic and English.

> At least as close

means either

> equally close or more close

What is being said to be possibly "not less" is the concept of "closeness" rather than Euclidean distance itself.

If you want to think about it mathematically

> A is closer to me than B

means the distance between me and A < the distance between me and B.

> A is as close to me as B

means the distance between me and A = the distance between me and B.

> A is at least as close to me as B

means

> the distance between me and A <= the distance between me and B.